# How to disallow second OpenVPN client with the same key?

Tags: openvpn, vpn-client

I've setup my openvpn server, but I have this problem:

Clients connects in this order:

1. client_A connects succesfully to server using it's own key.
2. client_B connects to server using client_A's key and gets same ip as client_A.

When I try to ping client_A packets goes to client_B instead of client_A.

I don't have `duplicate-cn` in my server config.

How can I prevent this behavior? I want to kick client_B immediately and keep only client_A.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't.

What is wrong in your scenario is `client_B connects to server using client_A's key` that should never happen.

it's like if you'd says "what wrong ? I just published my login/password, and someone else used it ... !,"

clients keys is like their email login/password. they don't publish it, they dont communicate it, they don't exchange it, or it may be a professional misconduct.

you can just revoke the keys, and provide some news one with a private password, or make them sign a conduct agreement to not share their keys.

if you can't, [use 2fa](https://openvpn.net/blog/openvpn-mfa-setup-community-edition/) instead.